# Why bind-mount /var/tmp to /tmp?

Tags: linux, mount, fstab

I've read in several places that it is recommended to bind-mount /var/tmp to /tmp.
This can be done by adding the following line to /etc/fstab:

/tmp /var/tmp none rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,bind 0 0

How can this be beneficial? In other words why should we bind-mount /var/tmp to /tmp ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Filesystem HierarchyStandard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) says:

- `/tmp/` Temporary files. Often not preserved between system reboots.
- `/var/tmp/` Temporary files to be preserved between reboots.

For example: if an processus is launched every 5 minutes and needs to store some data between every launch, it will rather store them in /var/tmp/.

Answer (score 6):

There may be some *system safety* reason for bind-mounting `/var/tmp`.

By mounting `/var/tmp`, the path `/var/tmp` will stop being an ordinary subdirectory within the `/` root filesystem and become a distinctly mounted filesystem. This mounting would - as indicated by your example fstab line -

> `/tmp /var/tmp none rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,bind 0 0`

enable us to trigger some safety related mount options like `nosuid` and `noexec` which would act as some additional safety mechanism to avoid the execution of any potentially distrusted temporary data in the `/var/tmp` path.

Comment: But that would also work if you simply had `/var/tmp` reside on an individual partition. It's not really related to bind-mounting `/var/tmp` *to `/tmp`*...

Comment: @DevSolar Of course the answer is only one suggested motive for bind-mounting `/var/tmp` to `tmp`. The `/etc/fstab` code of the OP contained the `nosuid,noexec and nodev` flags and this suggested the motive which I presented as one potential reason. Consider that /tmp and /var/tmp are likely places where attackers might have write access. Therefore bind-mounting the directory can tighten security a bit more. This is why I used bind-mounts.

Comment: @DevSolar Your suggestion about the option for an individual partition provokes an additional reason for the OP's question. `/tmp` might reside on a faster device as the `/` root filesystem (and by this also the `/var` directory) and the of the given fstab line wanted to have any temporary data using the same (i.e. faster) device as /tmp. Possibly there are still some other conceivable reasons we have not thought about. If you can find one that is in very closely linked to the `/var/tmp` and `/tmp` directories I'd be glad to learn.